# Not getting Goal name using Google Analytics gapi

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have to get goal name using gapi.
Also, I have seen all dimensions and metrics, but i don't get goal name.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Can anyone help me how can i get goal name. Do we have any dimension like ga:goalName?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the Goal name associated with a goal is to go though the [management api Goal list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list)

There isn't any way to get the goal name or number as a dimension on the GA website or via the API.  [Goal Dimension and metric list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=goal_conversions)

Comment: Thanks this is what i want. Thanks for your hard work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get active goals and their name then please use http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/google-analytics-management-api-phpinterface-for-php

Replace *PROTOCOL* with **https**

After that just change gManagementApi.class.php file
const GOOGLE_MANAGEMENT_URL ='PROTOCOL://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/datasources/ga/accounts';

to

const GOOGLE_MANAGEMENT_URL = 'PROTOCOL://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts';

Thanks,